# Общий скрипт для нескольких объектов в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Делаю 3d стрелялку в unity. У меня есть враги, которые спавнятся на сцене через каждые 10 сек и если кол-во жизней равно 0 исчезают. Возникает проблема когда пуля попадает во врага, то отнимаются жизни у всех клонов врага, находящихся на сцене.
Я понимая, что это возникает из-за того, что у них один скрипт, но что сделать чтобы каждый скрипт работал не зависимо от другого.

Нанесение урона

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed_bullet;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed_bullet);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            enemy.heartEnemy -= 20;
        }
    }
}
```

Движение врага

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{

    private GameObject hero_obj;
    public float speed;
    public static int heartEnemy;

    void Start()
    {
        hero_obj = GameObject.Find("hero");
        heartEnemy = 100;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        MoveEnemy();
        CheckHeart();
    }

    void MoveEnemy()
    {
        transform.LookAt(hero_obj.transform.position);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, hero_obj.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    void CheckHeart()
    {
        if (heartEnemy <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: код логики нанесения повреждений в студию, пожалуйста...

Comment: код логики нанесения повреждений в студии

Comment: Где? Есть `enemy.heartEnemy -= 20;`, но откуда взялась переменная `enemy`? Почему не `coll.GetComponent<enemy>().heartEnemy -= 20`?

Comment: @Yaroslav, `enemy` это клас со статичным полем **heartEnemy**...
 @Veter_ok, Вам бы матчасть подучить. Статичные поля ОБЩИЕ для всех экземпляров класса. Поэтому здоровье тратится одновременно у ВСЕХ, потому что здоровье у них обще...

Comment: Не обратил внимание. OMG! WTF? Такого и представить себе не мог. А как вам это в голову пришло? Нахрена? В чём функция?

Comment: Переписал код, всё заработало. Спасибо! Просто я как-то гугли как обратиться к переменной из другого скрипта, и нашёл эту конструкцию `public static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вопрос? У тебя пули как ракеты летят с двигателем и ускоряются еще по ходу движения? Физика у тебя явно не правильная. Пуле прикладывается сила один только раз, а у тебя каждый кадр. Да и манипуляции с физикой должны делаться в FixedUpdate(). Это во первых.

Во-вторых, я не удивлюсь, что с тем, как ты ловишь попадания пуль, у тебя пули просто пролетают через врага и летят дальше. Для быстро движущихся объектов надо использовать другие методы определения попадания.. Особенно, если у тебя fps не очень высокий.

Ну, на счет того, что поле health у тебя статическое тебе уже сказали. А чтобы каждый раз не вызывать GetComponent(), что дорого, лучше бы ты кешировал всех своих Enemy в словаре где-нибудь в общем классе сцены `Dictionary<Collider, Enemy>` EnemyMap, тогда можно будет делать типа такого:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
{
    if(BattlController.EnemyMap.TryGetValue(coll, out var enemy)) //BattleController это первое, что пришло мне в голову в качестве класса, который был бы общим для всех объектов карты. Кстати, в этом случае словарь EnemyMap мог бы быть статическим
    {
      enemy.heartEnemy -= 20; // по-хорошему пуля не должна знать, как отбавлять здоровье, лучше это вынести в класс Enemy в отедльный метод.. было бы типа enemy.TakesDamage(20);
//Или вообще не связывать эти классы , а запускать событие. Но это в твоем случае пока рано..
    }

    // сравнивать теги больше не нужно. Да и коряво это так делать coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy"
}
```

То, что ты каждый кадр проверяешь здоровье врага `CheckHeart();` в Update, тоже коряво. Проверяй умер ли тогда, когда здоровье обновляется и все. Зачем каждый кадр то это делать?

Когда ты пуле придаешь силу `transform.forward * speed_bullet` , где гарантия, что у пули то же самое направление, что и у ствола? Если она летит в нужную сторону, то тебе просто повезло.

Destroy у врагов вряд ли надо вызывать, просто клади их в пул для повторного использования. Я не удивлюсь, если ты и пули каждый раз спаунишь, вызывая Instantiate. Короче, у тебя всё пока довольно колхозно.